# Maven build error on MAcOS : " unmappable character for encoding UTF-8"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3

I working on MacOs on Eclipse Kepler.

I'm trying to run maven with UTF8 to be OS dependent.

I think I have tried a lot of solutions that seems to work for others not for me.

```
export JAVA _TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

When i Run in console :

```
mvn -version


Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

But i am running maven via Eclipse and Eclipse says platform encoding macRoman...
When i run a

> clean install

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /Users/JP/git/CleanOmicsTracer/EMBEDDED
Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

In my pom.xml i have setted as this to set UTF-8:

```
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
     <project.resources.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.resources.sourceEncoding>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <tag>${project.build.finalName}</tag>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>localhost</server>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <update>true</update>
            <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
            <username>jp</username>
            <password>camille</password>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>

        <fork>true</fork>
            <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
             <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>localhost</server>
            <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>


     <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.6</version>
     <configuration>
     <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
     <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
     </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

It's not working, the é and è in my .java create an error :

When i change in maven-compile-plugin this line

> macRoman

, it will be ok but no more Os Dependent and characters will be misunderstood in my other computer in linux.

When i clean install, the ouput is ok for ressources but nothing is done for the compiler :

> [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @
>   CleanOmicsTracer --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered
>   resources. [INFO] Copying 36 resources [INFO]
>
> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @
>   CleanOmicsTracer --- [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
>   [INFO] Compiling 142 source files to
>   /Users/JP/git/CleanOmicsTracer/target/classes [INFO]
>
> [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources
>   (default-testResources) @ CleanOmicsTracer --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8'
>   encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] skip non existing
>   resourceDirectory /Users/JP/git/CleanOmicsTracer/src/test/resources

**UPDATE :** I change eclipse configuration to use /usr/share/maven and not the embeded version.
I still have errors whereas this time the platform encoding is well set to UFT-8:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /usr/share/java/maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

[ERROR] /com/clb/genomic/lyon/validator/ParticipantExistenceValidator.java:[101,93] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project CleanOmicsTracer: Compilation failure
```

Comment: I remove the org.apache.maven.plugins, and now it's ok :)

Answer (score 2):

If it works when the platform encoding is set to MacRoman but fails when it is set to UTF-8 then it means `ParticipantExistenceValidator` is not in UTF-8 encoding. You need to fix the file, not the configuration.

One easy way to do this is to use [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html) twice, first to convert MacRoman to unicode escapes and then again with `-reverse` to convert the escapes back into UTF-8.